# Errors mixup JQuery and Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have some troubles with JQuery and JQuery mobile.
When i click on the links in my page, i have this error :

**Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on page prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'bindRemove'**

I have tried to change the position of the link rel and scripts, but it breaks my design...

Someone have an idea ?

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Accueil</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

    <!-- CSS splashscreen -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/wemind/splashscreen.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/wemind/styles_wemind.css" />

    <!-- JS -->
    <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Scripts splashscreen -->
    <script src="js/jquery.splashscreen.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script_splashscreen.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="promoIMG" />
<div data-role="page" id="main-page">
    <div id="actionbar-main"><img src="img/ic_launcher.png" /></div>
    <p class="text-accueil">Qui &ecirc;tes-vous ?</p>
    <div id="student-link"><a href="login.php" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/ic_student.png" /></a></div>
    <p class="wemind-font">Student</p>
    <div id="horiz-sep-main"><img src="img/ic_sep.png" /></div>
    <div id="parent-link"><a href="login.php" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/ic_teacher.png" /></a></div>
    <p class="wemind-font">Teacher</p>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should use the same version of jQM CSS and JS, so use css 1.4.5 instead of 1.4.4. Also you only need one jQM CSS file, either the minimized or not, but don't include both.

Comment: I did this : jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css , jquery 1.11.2.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js, and i have the same result... :(

Comment: Do you have any script in the linked page that is trying to run on document ready instead of the jQM pagecreate/pageshow events?

Comment: No. i have a script for the splashscreen on document ready on the page i just written up there, but the page login.php have just the JQery and JQuery mobile scripts

Answer (score 0):

Something in your `js/` scripts is trying to act on a Mobile widget before it's initialized. Find whatever function is using bindRemove as a parameter and call it without any arguments first to initialize its widget before you call bindRemove.

Comment: I see that, but i shouldn't have to change the JQuery scripts, shouldn't i ? Maybe my included scripts are not compatible ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this :

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
                window.location = $(this).attr("href");
        });
    });
</script>
```

i put this in the 
but when i logout, i'm redirected to this page and the problem appear again...
I should be able to click a link without problem, it's very odd with a code that simple !